# Peculiar PHP behaviour while connecting to local mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

Disclaimer: I am *extremely* unfamiliar with PHP. I always hated working in it so I never bothered learning about it.

I was following [this](https://www.techiediaries.com/php-react-rest-api-crud-tutorial/) tutorial since it describes exactly what I'm working on (a front end application that only uses PHP to interface with the database) and ran into a very weird problem.

If I mistype my database password, I get an error message saying `TypeError: this.state.contacts.map is not a function` (contacts is my variable). This is pretty much expected since failing to connect to the database also means it won't be able to fetch the data.

If I write it correctly, it tells me the file from which it takes the database login doesn't exist! `GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/contacts.php 404 (Not Found)`

Stack trace:

```
[Mon Jul 15 15:20:29 2019] 127.0.0.1:61859 [200]: /api/contacts.php
[Mon Jul 15 15:36:18 2019] 127.0.0.1:62737 [200]: /
[Mon Jul 15 15:36:20 2019] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: PATH_INFO in C:\[...]\Desktop\php-react-rest-api-crud\api\contacts.php on line 11
[Mon Jul 15 15:36:20 2019] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: id in C:\[...]\Desktop\php-react-rest-api-crud\api\contacts.php on line 21
[Mon Jul 15 15:36:20 2019] 127.0.0.1:62738 [404]: /api/contacts.php
```

It gets it fine the first time, then says it doesnt exist.

Full code [here](https://github.com/thMike/php-react-rest-api-crud)
Notice: I'm aware it's improper code, I'm just trying to get a feel for how to structure my project.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "reactdb";
$id = '';
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
switch ($method) {
  case 'GET':
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from contacts" . ($id ? " where id=$id" : '');
    break;
  case 'POST':
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $city = $_POST["city"];
    $contact = $_POST["contact"];
    $sql = "insert into contacts (name, email, city, contact) values ('$name', '$email', '$city', '$contact')";
    break;
}
// run SQL statement
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
// die if SQL statement failed
if (!$result) {
  http_response_code(404);
  die(mysqli_error($con));
}
if ($method == 'GET') {
  if (!$id) echo '[';
  for ($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    echo ($i > 0 ? ',' : '') . json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result));
  }
  if (!$id) echo ']';
} elseif ($method == 'POST') {
  echo json_encode($result);
} else {
  echo mysqli_affected_rows($con);
}
$con->close();
```

Edit: My question doesn't have anything to do with the undefined indexes. The problem has to do with PHP not being able to recognize the existence of a file it already uses.

Edit 2: Here's the index.php file that creates the error I'm asking about:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>PHP| MySQL | React.js | Axios Example</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Babel Compiler -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id='root'></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

        class ContactForm extends React.Component {
        state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            contact: '',
            city: '',
        }

    handleFormSubmit( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();


        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', this.state.name)
        formData.append('email', this.state.email)
        formData.append('city', this.state.city)
        formData.append('country', this.state.contact)

        console.log("Trying to contact the API...");

        axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/contacts.php',
            data: formData,
            config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response)

        })
        .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response)
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
        <form>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}/>

            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" value={this.state.email}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}/>

            <label>Contact</label>
            <input type="text" name="contact" value={this.state.contact}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ country: e.target.value })}/>

            <label>City</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" value={this.state.city}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ city: e.target.value })}/>

            <input type="submit" onClick={e => this.handleFormSubmit(e)} value="Create Contact" />
        </form>);
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    contacts: []
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Contact Management</h1>
        <table border='1' width='100%' >
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>City</th>  
        </tr>

        {this.state.contacts.map((contact) => (
        <tr>
            <td>{ contact.name }</td>
            <td>{ contact.email }</td>
            <td>{ contact.contact }</td>
            <td>{ contact.city }</td>
        </tr>
        ))}
        </table>

        <ContactForm />

        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = '/api/contacts.php'

    console.log("Trying to contact the API...");

    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ contacts: data })
      console.log(this.state.contacts)
     })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The database has 1 table with 4 fields: name, email, city, contact.

Comment: The php code to hit the MySQL database, when it gets errors, returns `false` rather than the variable you expected. So, if you don't check it before trying to use it, you get errors like this.

Comment: @O.Jones So it tells me the file doesn't exist because it has a different error?

Comment: File??? what file??? I don't see any reference to a file in your example code. Do you mean *result set*, the stuff you get from `mysqli_fetch_object()`?

Comment: @O.Jones there are 2 files in the example code I give. In the index.php I am referring to the file you posted as example code. When I run the server, the chrome console claims this file doesn't exist (api/contacts.php)

Comment: The  devtools console can't see your `contacts.php` file. That file isn't downloaded to your browser. Rather, the php program in it is run, on your web server, on behalf of your browser when you use the `axios()` invocation. When `contacts.php` runs on your web server, it connects to your MySQL server to handle the data inserts and retrievals.

Comment: @O.Jones Okay, that explains why there's a difference when the password is wrong. Thank you.

Is that article just wrong then?

Comment: @Dharman I even added a notice saying this code is just for playing around. I think the fact that I'm saving the password in a PHP file is a bigger security issue.

Comment: The line `$id = $_GET['id'];` is trying to get the `id` from the URL via `GET`. It doesn't seem like you are setting that in your API's URL when calling this thing, so that line fails. It's odd though that the Tutorial has SQL that allows for no `$id` to be set later on though when it can't handle a unset `id` in the GET.

Comment: My comment was not only about security, but proper code. SQL injection is a bug which can break your software. Even if you are just trying to learn something simple you should start with prepared statements. That tutorial is pretty bad and I would not recommend to learn from it.

Comment: The first error about `PATH_INFO` is throwing from here `$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/'));` which may be causing the downstream `$_GET['id']` issue (really that `$_GET` should never fire since the `$method` is `post` from your `axios/html`.

Comment: That may be because of your `php` set up or it may because it's `localhost`... Not sure why that `$_SERVER` variable isn't availabe. You *may* be able to get around it by swapping that line to `$request = explode('/', trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'));`

Comment: @Dharman I am aware of SQL injections. I appreciate you go around sharing this information since a lot of people absolutely ignore security. I'm saying it's irrelevant to me since I'm aware of it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It gets it fine the first time, then says it doesnt exist.
>
> ...
>
> Edit: My question doesn't have anything to do with the undefined indexes. The problem has to do with PHP not being able to recognize the existence of a file it already uses.

It does exist.

Both times the code is being executed properly, but on the second time, the execution is following this path:

```
if (!$result) {
  http_response_code(404);
  die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

And returns a 404 (which you are interpreting like doesn't exists)